# Is it possible to mark a property of a parameter as null/not null after a function returns?

Tags: c#, annotations, nullable-reference-types, c#-9.0

If I have a function `bool Foo(string? input)`, then I can annotate it to indicate that if the return is `true` then `input` is not null:

```
public static bool Foo([NotNullWhen(true)] string? input)
```

Is it possible to do that (or something similar) for a property of an argument? I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
public class AClass { string? NullableString {get;set;}}
public static bool Foo([PropertyNotNullWhen(true, nameof(AClass.NullableString))] AClass input)
```

I don't think `MemberNotNullWhen` will work in this case, because it only applies to methonds, properties, and indexers and not the arguments to them.

Comment: This isn't possible at the moment. I would recommend opening a discussion on https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/new with your real world example. I think this is definitely something that they will consider for a future language version if there's enough need.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt Looks like that is indeed the answer - I'll give you the tick if you post it as one. I opened an issue over at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/49640 , if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that C# added support for this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis

In your case you need `NotNullWhen`

| Attribute | Category | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AllowNull | Precondition | A non-nullable parameter, field, or property may be null. |
| DisallowNull | Precondition | A nullable parameter, field, or property should never be null. |
| MaybeNull | Postcondition | A non-nullable parameter, field, property, or return value may be null. |
| NotNull | Postcondition | A nullable parameter, field, property, or return value will never be null. |
| MaybeNullWhen | Conditional postcondition | A non-nullable argument may be null when the method returns the specified bool value. |
| NotNullWhen | Conditional postcondition | A nullable argument won't be null when the method returns the specified bool value. |
| NotNullIfNotNull | Conditional postcondition | A return value, property, or argument isn't null if the argument for the specified parameter isn't null. |
| MemberNotNull | Method and property helper methods | The listed member won't be null when the method returns. |
| MemberNotNullWhen | Method and property helper methods | The listed member won't be null when the method returns the specified bool value. |
| DoesNotReturn | Unreachable code | A method or property never returns. In other words, it always throws an exception. |
| DoesNotReturnIf | Unreachable code | This method or property never returns if the associated bool parameter has the specified value. |